# Spring JPA custom query parameters are not ordered correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a custom query like so

```
List<Product> findBypropertyIdAndIdInAndCreateDateGreaterThanEqual(Integer propertyId, List<Integer> ids, Date createDate);
```

After turning on Log4j I see in the logs that the parameters are mismatched.

For example in the logs I see

```
[Trace] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binging parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [12]

 [Trace] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binging parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [3]

 [Trace] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binging parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2019-05-01]
```

Those are correct for the 3 parameters I am passing in but they are coming across as parameter 2, 3 and 3 instead of 1, 2, and 3. So the query returns an empty result.

So in this test case:

```
Integer propertyId = "12"
List<Integer> ids = 3 (it only has one integer in this case)
Date createDate = 2019-05-01
```

So I am confused as to why this is happening. Why are they mistmatched? Why is parameter 3 binding twice with parameter 2 and parameter 3?

I turned on Log4j as the code compiled but my results were not returning from the database.

Comment: In the logs the queries are all starting with "select TOP(?) . . . . " And later in the preparedstatement section of the logs I see "select TOP(atP0) . . . " My parameters appear as atP1, atP2, and atP3 which corresponds to the trace binding numbers. This is why they are shifted. Where is TOP being inserted? My repository interface method is findBypropertyIdAndIdInAndCreateDateGreaterThanEqual(Integer propertyId, List<Integer> ids, Date createDate)

Comment: Since I inherited this code where would someone force "top" to be used for all interface methods? I searched the code base for "select top" and even "top(* with nothing significant returned. So how do I get rid of this?

Comment: So no one can think of how "top(?)" is getting inserted into my queries when I am not using the spring jpa keyword "top" as in "findTOP300. . . "?